# Cannot get context.rotate to show image properly

Tags: html5-canvas

I need to rotate the image 180 degrees, but when I add in the rotate code, the image becomes a square.

```
var moulding_matte_canvas_height = [],
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = 5.171363636363637,
  opening_i = 0,
  rotate = 180 * Math.PI / 180,
  i = 2;

moulding_matte_canvas_height[0] = 225;
canvas.width = 285;
canvas.height = 335;
img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.asa.tframes.org:1881/system/components/compimg/80ac89fad42cf14561b641df241bf406/pattern';

function moulding_get_segment_width(img_width, opening_i)
{
  return 175;
}

//
$(img).on("load", function() {
ctx.save(); 
ctx.translate(width, moulding_matte_canvas_height[opening_i]); 
//ctx.rotate(rotate);
//ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, moulding_get_segment_width(img.width, i), width);
ctx.restore();   

//
});
$("#mattes").append(canvas); /*appending the canvas*/
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/onpa628e/1/

(Whitespace is intentional due to other elements that will be drawn and the red next to the image is just for clarity)

Without rotate:

[image]

With rotate:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image looks like a square, because it's only showing a tiny portion on the canvas. This happens because `translate` is only moving ~ 5px (your "`width`" variable) on the x axis.

[Here's your example modified](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jt7134e9/4/) with a higher x value.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured this out a while ago, but didn't get to update the question.